# Calendar invite using msflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I run below flow I am getting below issues, though I configured required attendees in shortlisted list (pls refer below for list schema) but I'm not sure why its not displaying in the Mail but when I click scheduled assistant tab in my outlook calendar for this invitation required attendees available

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Flow Tested

Can you do the following for us? 1) Add a Compose action in your flow. 2) Compose action should return your Attendees variable. 3) Run your flow again 4) Open your flow run and check the value in the new Compose action 5) Paste a screenshot + value here, in your question –
[image]

[image]

List schema
[image]

Comment: Can you do the following for us? 1) Add a Compose action in your flow. 2) Compose action should return your Attendees variable. 3) Run your flow again 4) Open your flow run and check the value in the new Compose action 5) Paste a screenshot + value here, in your question

Comment: please note i added as per your request in above question section . Please refer under  Flow tested as per your request and added the steps you requested